# certificateValidationMode seems to be ignored by Azure

Tags: azure, web-config, x509certificate

I'm developing a solution (web app) for windows azure that uses WSFederation for authentication. Since im on azure testing phase (local tests were successful) i've decided to use the same self signed certificate i've been using for local testing.

The problem here is that i'm getting an error saying that "***The X.509 certificate CN=mytestsite.com.br is not in the trusted people store. The X.509 certificate CN=mytestsite.com.br chain building failed. The certificate that was used has a trust chain that cannot be verified***".

This error makes complete sense because it's a self-signed certificate, but since im on a staging enviroment (and I would absolutally hate to ask my sponsor for extra-budget for a valid certificate right now...) I would like to use the self-signed one anyway. So I changed the ***certificateValidationMode*** to "None", but I still get the same validation error... It seems that the validation mode is being ignored!!!

Does anyone knows what can I do to make things work? (buy a valid certificate would be my last shot because they're quite expensive for my budget at this point...)

Comment: Post relevant web.config sections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it by adding "certificateValidationMode" to the STS web.config.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use the self-signed cert, use code to "deploy" it to your `Trusted People` store, and all should be well. This will be closer to real production use anyways (and if you use PeerTrust in production, you'll have to do the same thing there as well, even with a *real* certificate).

```
    private static void CopyServerCertIntoPeopleStore()
    {
        var myStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        myStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        var peopleStore = new X509Store(StoreName.TrustedPeople, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        var cert = myStore.Certificates.Find(
                                X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
                                SettingFetcher.GetSetting(SettingFetcher.SettingType.ApplicationVariable, "WcfServiceCertificateThumbprint"),
                                true
                              ).OfType<X509Certificate2>().First();

        peopleStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
        peopleStore.Add(cert);
    }
```

Use something like this, just replace the SettingFetcher with `RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue` or whatever to grab the thumbprint.

Comment: i didn't try this yet (because i cant deploy myself to azure) but will it work on azure cloud services?

Comment: We use this exact code right now in both Worker Roles and Web Roles. The **only** part of it that shouldn't be copy/paste worthy for you would be **1)** the mechanism to identify the certificate to pull (although, this might work too) and **2)** My `SettingFetcher` code to go pull a Thumbprint from a configuration store. Otherwise, this code should work for you.

Comment: +1 thank you but I managed to do this by adding "certificateValidationMode" to the STS web.config also... Later I'll try your solution...